# Convert Pandas object to multiple columns

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I have imported the following data within a CSV file:

- 01/01/2014 00:00:00, 50.031
- 01/01/2014 00:00:01, 50.026
- 01/01/2014 00:00:02, 50.019
- 01/01/2014 00:00:03, 50.008
- etc

I successfully have converted the "object" in the first column to a datetime using:

```
df= pd.read_csv("myfile.csv",names=['DateTime','Freq'])
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], coerce=True)
```

The problem is, it's a very big CSV file (35 million rows) and it's dog slow. Is there a more efficient ways of converting the first column to datetime?

I would also like to split the date and the time into separate columns.

Comment: You can pass param `parse_dates=[0]` for `read_csv` so try `df= pd.read_csv("myfile.csv",names=['DateTime','Freq'], parse_dates=[0])` this will parse the first column as a datetime, it should be significantly faster

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but not really much of a speed up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in the [`read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function itself, you can use the argument `parse_dates` , and send in the list of columns to parse as date to it. Example -

```
df= pd.read_csv("myfile.csv",names=['DateTime','Freq'],parse_dates=['DateTime'])
```

Demo -

```
In [41]: import io

In [42]: s = """Date, SomeNum
   ....: 01/01/2014 00:00:00, 50.031
   ....: 01/01/2014 00:00:01, 50.026
   ....: 01/01/2014 00:00:02, 50.019
   ....: 01/01/2014 00:00:03, 50.008"""

In [43]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),parse_dates=['Date'])

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
                 Date   SomeNum
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00    50.031
1 2014-01-01 00:00:01    50.026
2 2014-01-01 00:00:02    50.019
3 2014-01-01 00:00:03    50.008

In [45]: df['Date']
Out[45]:
0   2014-01-01 00:00:00
1   2014-01-01 00:00:01
2   2014-01-01 00:00:02
3   2014-01-01 00:00:03
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Timing results of different methods for a csv with 1 million records -

```
In [92]: def func1():
   ....:     df = pd.read_csv('a.csv',names=['DateTime','Freq'])
   ....:     df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], coerce=True,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
   ....:     return df
   ....:

In [96]: def func2():
   ....:     return pd.read_csv('a.csv',names=['DateTime','Freq'],parse_dates=['DateTime'])
   ....:

In [97]: %timeit func1()
1 loops, best of 3: 6.5 s per loop

In [98]: %timeit func2()
1 loops, best of 3: 652 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked, but seemed to take longer than my original effort.

Comment: Hmmm, I would have thought trying doing it in `read_csv()` itself, would be faster. Time to do some timing tests with large datasets.

Comment: @AnthonyW: Both this this solution and your original solution can be made much faster if you specify the date format (use the `format` parameter). At the moment, pandas has to infer the datetime format - this is computationally expensive in comparison.

Comment: @AnthonyW Are you sure you removed the `pd.to_datetime()` when using this method?

Comment: @ajcr roger that! Much better. Thanks

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes. The big difference seems to be:
    `df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', coerce=True)`

Comment: @AnthonyW I have added the timing results for a dataset with 1 million rows. Unless you are doing something very wrong, you should be able to see huge improvement of using `parse_dates` argument.

Comment: So I tried:
`def f1():
    df= pd.read_csv("f20141.csv",names=['DateTime','Frequency'], skiprows=1)
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', coerce=True)
    return df
def f2():
    return pd.read_csv("f20141.csv",names=['DateTime','Freq'],parse_dates=['DateTime'], skiprows=1)
%timeit f1()
%timeit f2()`

`f1`: 1 loops, best of 3: 21 s per loop
`f2`: 1 loops, best of 3: 4min 3s per loop

The only thing different was the `skiprows` parameter??

Comment: f1() took only 21seconds and f2() took 4 mins?